# Evaluation of $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k+\alpha N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The series 
$$S(\alpha,N)=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k+\alpha N}$$
can be evaluated as:
$$S(\alpha,N)=\Psi(N+1+\alpha N)-\Psi(1+\alpha N)$$
The limit $$L(\alpha)=\lim_{N \to \infty}S(\alpha)$$
can be evaluated for different values of the parameter $\alpha$. For example: $L(1)=\ln(2)$, $L(2)=\ln\frac{3}{2}$ and so on. Is there a formula for $L(\alpha)$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb N$?
Thanks.

Comment: $S(\alpha,N)$ is a Riemann sum: $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{\frac{k}{N}+\alpha} \longrightarrow \int_0^1\frac{dx}{x + \alpha} = \log( 1 +\frac{1}{\alpha})\text{ as }N \to \infty$$

Comment: @achillehui I hope you will consider posting your comment as an answer, it is much better than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$\psi(x)=\ln x-\frac{1}{2x}+O(x^{-2})$$
as $x\rightarrow\infty$, your limit is equal to $\displaystyle \ln\frac{1+\alpha}{\alpha}$.

Comment: But of course the Riemann sum method of achille is more elementary.

Comment: @GEdgar And nicer. Imo he should post his comment as an answer, and I encourage the OP to change the accepted answer in that case.